# Accessing a multidimensional array passed from a PHP script to a AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

I'm passing a multidimensional array to my AJAX success function like this:

```
$response = array();

$response['message']['name'] = $name;
$response['message']['phone'] = $phone;

echo json_encode( $response );
die();
```

Now I'm having problems accessing this data using jQuery. I've tried outputting the data using the following which strangely works in Chrome but not in FireFox, IE, Safari or Chrome mobile.

```
jQuery( '#message' ).html( data.message.name );
```

The console is displaying this `TypeError: data.message is undefined`

Hoping someone can help let me know where I am going wrong.

My AJAX call and success function:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        'action': 'quote',
        'security': security,
        'name': name,
        'phone': phone,
},
success:function(data) {

    if ( data.message.name == 'Ben' ) {
        jQuery( '#message' ).html( data.message.name );         
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

},
```

**UPDATE:** I pinpointed the problem to WordPress. Specifically `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)` must be used as it executes for users not logged-in. I was using just `wp_ajax_(action)` which executes for logged in users only. Note I was logged-in using Chrome, and not logged-in using FF, IE and Safari which totally explains why I was seeing the undefined console message when using these browsers.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Can you show the ajax function?

Comment: It may be data[0].message.name

Comment: Is your `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: Try to give back a json header
`code`
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
`code`

Comment: I've updated my question with my AJAX call and success function

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I tried data[0].message.name with no luck. Ohgodwhy - yes it is. Please see my updated question

Comment: I am just wondering what 'ajax_url' is set correctly in Firefox? can you do not console.log(ajax_url); before ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Extend your PHP code with following line that send the JSON header to the retrieving data:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

And have you tried following?

```
data['message']['name'];
```

Try also to output your `data` variable with

```
console.log(data);
```

to find out if it's an array or an object.

In your browserside developertools you will probably find the `network` tab. It will show you the AJAX request with errors, request and response data...

Have you tried to implement an error handler like this?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

From the documentation:

> jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
>
> An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

Comment: The network tabs shows nothing unfortunately. Also, I tried `data['message']['name'];` which results in the same console error. Adding the header had no effect either

Comment: I don't understand why it works perfectly in Chrome yet in FF, IE and Safari it falls on it's backside

Comment: When the network tab shows nothing, than there occures no AJAX request... Are you calling your javascript function after DOM is ready?

Comment: There must be an AJAX request because it works in Chrome. Yes, my script is wrapped in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ...`

Comment: You forgot to mention your WordPress context ;-)

Comment: Apologies for that, I didn't think it was relevant... could kick myself :)